# How to calculate an average across multiple columns only if none of the value is missing in Python Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This is my data:

[image]

How can I get the average value of all the columns with string `_var` and if none of these column has missing value `NaN`?

Comment: kindly post your expected output, and do not post pics pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `mean()` with `skipna=False`.

```
# extract the columns based on prefix 
cols = [col for col in df.columns.tolist() if col.startswith('_var')]
df['special_mean'] = df[cols].mean(skipna=False, axis=1)

# or using @sammywemmy's method
df['special_mean'] = df.filter(like='_var').mean(skipna=False, axis=1)
```

Comment: you can use ``df.filter(like='_var').mean(axis=1)``

Comment: @sammywemmy thanks, forgot that `mean()` skips the `NaN values